# Titanium Mapview Click Get the Lat and Long

Tags: titanium, android-mapview, appcelerator

I am looking to create a simple mapview in Titanium (appcelerator), but what I want/need to do is have the user click, or longpress on the the map and get the latitude and longitude from that selection on the map. The mapview does have a `mapview.addEventListener('click',function(evt))`, but I dont get a these values when clicked. Any help with this would be awesome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is very easy to just calculate the latitude and longitude from the click or longpress coordinates (if were not too zoomed out).  Use this function inside the event listener taken from [this question at Appcelerator Q&A:](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/132508/how-to-add-annotation-on-mapview-click-event)

```
var calculateLatLngfromPixels = function(mapview, xPixels, yPixels) {

    var region = mapview.actualRegion || mapview.region;
    var widthInPixels = mapview.rect.width;
    var heightInPixels = mapview.rect.height;

    // should invert because of the pixel reference frame
    heightDegPerPixel = -region.latitudeDelta / heightInPixels; 
    widthDegPerPixel = region.longitudeDelta / widthInPixels;

    return {
        lat : (yPixels - heightInPixels / 2) * heightDegPerPixel + region.latitude,
        lon : (xPixels - widthInPixels / 2) * widthDegPerPixel + region.longitude

    };
}
```

Note that you cant listen for a `longpress` event on the MapView itself so nest it in a regular container view and add the listeners to that. Example usage like this:

```
var container = Ti.UI.createView({
    top : 0,
    left : 0
});
container.add(mapview);

container.addEventListener('longpress', function(e) {
    var coordinate = calculateLatLngfromPixels(mapview, e.x, e.y);
    var longitude = coordinate.lat;
    var latitude = coordinate.lat;
});
```

This will work if your looking at a (relatively) small area of the earth, when youre fully zoomed out, you would have to use a mercator projection to get real coordinates because of the  curvature of the earth, if you want to be fully zoomed out then use the module.

Comment: It looks like the mapview.addEventListener('longpress'), or mapview.addEventListener('click') does not get fired in titanium. I've tried both events neither get fired or return values

Comment: Add the mapview into a container View, then add the listeners to the container view, it will work the exact same.

Comment: That seemed to do it, also if anyone else is having these type of issues be sure you set/predefine a region for the map when it loads. If you DONT the map region will be undefined thus causing an error. Thanks Josiah

Answer (score 0):

There is a module in the marketplace for that. It costs $0.99 to purchase and will give you the coordinates of a map https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/1334

Comment: I seen this but its IOS only. Thanks for the look up though.